# Why does MVC 5 SPA site "Login" page not work with saved passwords?

Tags: browser, knockout.js, knockout-mvc

I have an MVC 5 Single Page Application and the canned "Log in" page will not work with saved passwords - the validation code seems to think the fields are empty even when they're not:

[image: Login screen showing populated fields with error messages]

This effectively prevents the user from logging in. I've reproduced this in Firefox 30.0 on Windows and the default web browser on a few different Android devices.

From `_Login.cshtml`:

```
<div class="form-group">
        <label for="LoginUserName" class="col-md-2 control-label">User name</label>
        <div class="col-md-10">
            <input type="text" id="LoginUserName" class="form-control" data-bind="value: userName, hasFocus: true" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="LoginPassword" class="col-md-2 control-label">Password</label>
        <div class="col-md-10">
            <input type="password" id="LoginPassword" class="form-control" data-bind="value: password" />
        </div>
    </div>
```

I'm not very familiar with Knockout MVC, but it seems like it could be related. From `login.viewmodel.js`:

```
function LoginViewModel(app, dataModel) {
// Private state
var self = this,
    validationTriggered = ko.observable(false);

// Private operations
function initialize() {
    dataModel.getExternalLogins(dataModel.returnUrl, true /* generateState */)
        .done(function (data) {
            self.loadingExternalLogin(false);
            if (typeof (data) === "object") {
                for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                    self.externalLoginProviders.push(new ExternalLoginProviderViewModel(app, data[i]));
                }
            } else {
                self.errors.push("An unknown error occurred.");
            }
        }).fail(function () {
            self.loadingExternalLogin(false);
            self.errors.push("An unknown error occurred.");
        });
}

// Data
self.userName = ko.observable("").extend({ required: true });
self.password = ko.observable("").extend({ required: true });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This appears to be a either a [Knockout issue](https://github.com/knockout/knockout/issues/648)  or a browser issue depending on who you ask. Apparently the password autofill feature in Firefox doesn't trigger the DOM events that update the Knockout data binding.

I wound up with an inelegant workaround based on comments from the GitHub issue  - a script that uses jQuery to force the `change` event to fire on all `input` elements when the submit button is clicked:

```
<script>
function autoFillHack() {
    $(":input").trigger("change");
}
</script>
```

Further down in the `form`:

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" data-bind="click: login, disable: loggingIn" onclick="autoFillHack();">Log in</button>
```

I only have two `input` elements on that page but, as others pointed out, this may have undesirable effects depending on the situation.